# Progress bar labels display incorrectly when there are spaces

Tags: html, css

I have a progress bar:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="circle done">
            <span class="label">1</span>
            <span class="title">One Two Three</span>
    </div>
    <span class="bar done"></span>
    <div class="circle done">
            <span class="label">2</span>
            <span class="title">OneTwoThree</span>
    </div>
    <span class="bar half"></span>
    <div class="circle active">
            <span class="label">3</span>
            <span class="title">OneTwoThreeFour</span>
    </div>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <div class="circle">
            <span class="label">4</span>
            <span class="title">Five Six Seven</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

with the following css

```
 *, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
}

    .progress {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.progress .circle,
.progress .bar {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    width: 40px; height: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5da;
}
.progress .bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    height: 6px;
    top: -33px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.progress .circle .label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    border-radius: 32px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    color: #b5b5ba;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.progress .circle .title {
    color: #b5b5ba;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}

/* Done / Active */
.progress .bar.done,
.progress .circle.done {
     background: #eee;
}
.progress .bar.active {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEE 40%, #FFF 60%);
}
.progress .circle.done .label {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #8bc435;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.progress .circle.done .title {
        color: #444;
    }
    .progress .circle.active .label {
        color: #FFF;
        background: #0c95be;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }
    .progress .circle.active .title {
        color: #0c95be;
    }
```

The issue is with the first node and the last one, as the title for those has spaces in it. How can I fix that. I tried tweaking css but no success so far

Comment: Are you able to post a fiddle or codepen for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add nowrap to title element. It forces all words to one single line.

```
.progress .circle .title {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: what if I add line break to one of the titles?

Comment: If you use <br> tag it will work as usual and add a new line

Comment: actually when I add `<br/>`, the circle comes up higher

Comment: what happens when I add br, it pushes down the rest of the bar

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
}

    .progress {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.progress .circle,
.progress .bar {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    width: 40px; height: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5da;
}
.progress .bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    height: 6px;
    top: -33px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.progress .circle .label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    border-radius: 32px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    color: #b5b5ba;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.progress .circle .title {
    color: #b5b5ba;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    white-space: nowrap
}

/* Done / Active */
.progress .bar.done,
.progress .circle.done {
     background: #eee;
}
.progress .bar.active {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEE 40%, #FFF 60%);
}
.progress .circle.done .label {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #8bc435;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.progress .circle.done .title {
        color: #444;
    }
    .progress .circle.active .label {
        color: #FFF;
        background: #0c95be;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }
    .progress .circle.active .title {
        color: #0c95be;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
    <div class="circle done">
            <span class="label">1</span>
            <span class="title">One Two Three</span>
    </div>
    <span class="bar done"></span>
    <div class="circle done">
            <span class="label">2</span>
            <span class="title">OneTwoThree</span>
    </div>
    <span class="bar half"></span>
    <div class="circle active">
            <span class="label">3</span>
            <span class="title">OneTwoThreeFour</span>
    </div>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <div class="circle">
            <span class="label">4</span>
            <span class="title">Five Six Seven</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! One more thing - what if I insert <br/> in the middle of one title, how can I align eveything correctly in that case?